# How to handle duplicate key with batch insert in Jooq?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I need to insert a large number of rows into MySQL database and if they are duplicate, just update columns.

This is what I have:

```java
dslContext
    .insertInto(
        USER,
        USER.ID,
        USER.NAME
    )
    .valuesOfRows(
        profiles
            .stream()
            .collect(
                toRowArray(
                    x -> DSL.val(x.getId())
                    x -> DSL.val(x.getName())
                )
            )
    )
    .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
    .set(USER.NAME, ???)
    .execute();
```

How should I handle duplicates in this case? The JooQ documentation's example is `set(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, "Koontz")` which uses a fixed value to update. But here many rows are being inserted. How can I tell jooq "if row is a duplicate, just update user name?"

Answer (score 1):

Starting from jOOQ 3.17, you can use [`DSL.excluded(USER.NAME)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#excluded(org.jooq.Field)), which is PostgreSQL's version of the [MySQL `VALUES (NAME)` function or `NEW.NAME` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). So:

```java
.set(USER.NAME, DSL.excluded(USER.NAME))
```

Comment: So, iiuc, if I want to update only the NAME field in case of duplicate IDs in my example above, writing `.set(USER.ID, DSL.excluded(USER.ID))` will achieve that right?

Comment: No, then you would have to write exactly what I wrote in the answer. Here's the PostgreSQL docs for the `EXCLUDED` pseudo table (look for *"excluded"*): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html. It translates to `VALUES()` or `NEW` in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: For the record, you should read the word `EXCLUDED` as being the pseudo table of rows that have been excluded from insertion. That's how PostgreSQL defined it. jOOQ used the PostgreSQL naming, because 1) MySQL's naming is in flux, incompatibly, 2) `VALUES` already has a very different meaning within jOOQ and the SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions about how to do this for a table which has many columns (~20) without writing a large chunk of `x -> DSL.val(x.getName()` style block of code?

Comment: @Mahdi: Use the `set(Map)` overload, and `Stream.of(table.fields()).filter(...).collect(toMap(...)))`